# rust - Is there a way to mutate and keep reference to a variable inside a closure in?

Tags: rust, closures, observer-pattern, mutable

I have the following scenario:
A producer that runs in its own thread:

```rust
struct Consumer {}

impl Consumer {
  pub fn process(...) {
    ...
  }

  pub fn dump_stats(...) {
    ...
  }
}

struct Producer {
   callbacks: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&[u8]) + Sync + Send>>
}
...
impl Producer {

pub fn new() -> Self {
  Self {callbacks: Vec::new()}
}

pub fn add_callback<F>(&mut self, callback: F)
where F: 'static + Fn(&[u8]) + Sync + Send {
  self.callbacks.push(callback);
}

pub fn start(&self) -> () {
  // read data from network
  // and pass it on to consumers
  thread::spwan(move || {
    loop {
      let data: &[u8] = read_from_network(...);
      for callback in callbacks {
        callback(data);
      }
      thread.sleep()
    }
   }); 
}

}


fn main() -> () {
   let mut consumer = Consumer{};
   let producer = Producer::new();
   producer.register_callback(move |data: &[u8]| {
      consumer.process(data);
   });
   producer.start();

   loop {
     consumer.dump_stats();
     thread.sleep();
   }    
}
```

The obvious problem here is as soon as I move the consumer inside the closure, I lose it. Is there a way around to this or an alternative pattern to flesh out the same design?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `FnMut` rather than `Fn`?

Comment: @Coder-256 What would be the difference if it was an FnMut ?

Comment: `Fn` is for closures that hold only immutable references to their environment. You only need a shared reference to the closure to call it. `FnMut` is for closures that hold mutable references to their environment. As a result, you need a mutable reference to the closure in order to call it. `FnOnce` allows closures that move variables from their environment, and as a result you need to move them (and can only call them once). `Fn` is a supertrait of `FnMut`, which is a supertrait of `FnOnce`.

Comment: @Coder-256 assuming I use `FnMut`, would I be able to outside the scope of the closure?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that

Comment: @Coder-256 in the `main` function I am registering a callback which takes ownership the `consumer` variable: `producer.register_callback(move ...`. My question is: is there a way to make it a borrow and not a move.

Comment: Yes, simply delete `move`.

Comment: @Coder-256 I get this error when I did that: `closure may outlive the current function but it borrows 'consumer', which is owned by the current function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224071/discussion-between-coder-256-and-b2wc0ekkovlpn).

Comment: Use `let consumer = Arc::new(Consumer {})`, clone the Arc, and move the cloned Arc into the closure. Your code will retain the `Arc<Consumer>` which you can use to dump stats. If either thread needs `&mut` access to consumer, use `Arc::new(Mutex::new(Consumer {}))` and lock it to obtain a mutable reference.